# Why does the scroll bar sometimes shows up and sometimes it doesnt in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

If my chrome extension has too much data, a scroll bar shows up and some times it doesnt and just shows a white gap like the screenshot below. Is there a way to disable scroll bars completely? It's currently showing up in my body tag.

[image]

Comment: Might be https://crbug.com/821143. Try setting `overflow:overlay` on `html` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove always the scrollbar from the body
If you access with js

```
 document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // firefox, chrome
 document.body.scroll = "no"; // ie only
```

If you acess with css

```
body{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you are opening (new window) as a popup you need to target the (new window).documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';